# Default initialization throws exception

Tags: c++, exception

Suppose we have some class (call it `classs`) with the default constructor which can throw some exception. I need to use the object of that class in a function as follows:

```
try{
   classs c;
} catch(bad_init& b){
    //log
}
//if the class initialized succesfully
//do some with c
```

But `c` is declared in the `try`'s block scope and therefore is not visible in the function scope. How can I do that?

I don't want to wrap the whole function's body because there're some code throwing another kind of exception.

Comment: I do not think you can use keywords as variable/class names

Comment: @St.Antario... declare `c` as pointer before the `try` block, and allocate it using new inside `try`.

Comment: @sgarizvi Good advice, indeed. But is there away to avoid dynamic memory allocation here?

Comment: use dynamic allocation class *c=nullptr; try{c=new class ()} ...

Comment: Catch the exception higher up?

Comment: @St.Antario... You can create an explicit initialization member function (say `init`) and leave the default constructor empty.  Then declare `c` before `try`, and call `c.init()` inside try.

Comment: "I don't want to wrap the whole function's body because there're some code throwing another kind of exceptions." So, don't catch those. Catch only `bad_init`.

Comment: You can't get a valid object if the constructor of that object throws a exception. Throwing an exception just means the construction cannot finish normally.

Comment: @sgarizvi BTW, why did you suggest declaring a member function? I could declare it as a non-meber non-friend as well.

Comment: I can't see the problem. Just put "do some with c" inside the try block. Or justify why you can't do that.

Comment: @St.Antario... first thing that came to my mind! :)

Comment: "Another kind of exception" is not affected by your try-catch for bad_init. It will just "fall through" till getting caught elsewhere (or not oO). (You can also add another catch to the same try block.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly. As long as `c` is in scope, code has the right to assume if contains an alive object of type `classs`. If the constructor throws an exception, `c` will not be initialised and that cannot hold.

The correct way to do this is to wrap the entire scope of `c` in the `try` block. After all, code which uses `c` cannot do anything meaningful if `c` failed to initialise. If some other code later in that block can throw other exceptions and you don't want to catch them, just don't—let them propagate up the stack normally.

If you cannot use this approach is for some reason, you can resort to something like `boost::optional` and delayed init:

```
boost::optional<classs> c;
try {
  c = classs();
} catch (bad_init&) {
}
```

Or do something similar manually with `std::aligned_storage`, placement `new` and a conditional destructor call.

Comment: But what if I need to catch another exception?

Comment: @St.Antario Just add another `catch` clause for it. You can have as many `catch` clauses with a single `try` block as you want.

Answer (score 2):

a workaround is to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a;
try{
   a = std::make_unique<A>();
} catch(bad_init& b){
    //log
}
if (a){
 //do 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply catch the exception at the level of the caller. No need to make things complicated.

```
void functionThatThrows()
{
    classs c;
    // do something with c
}

void callerThatCatches()
{
    try {
        functionThatThrows();
    } catch(...) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is just to extend the try block until you no longer need your object :

```
try{
    classs c;
    //if the class initialized succesfully
    //do some with c
} catch(bad_init& b){
     //log
}
```